# Can the expression $\sum_{i=0}^{r} {r\choose i}{n-i+r-1\choose r-1} $ be simplified?

Tags: combinatorics

The problem originally was:

> Let $r$ be a positive integer, and $p_n$ the number of solutions to the equation: $|x_1|+|x_2|+...+|x_r|=n$ when $x_k$ may be positive, negative or zero.
>
> Find the generating function of $p_n$. The function should be written explicitly (for example, not as a multiplication of two infinite series).

What I did is:

$$(1+2x+2x^2+...)^r=(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{x}{1-x})^r=(\frac{1+x}{1-x})^r=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{r\choose i}{j+r-1\choose r-1}x^{i+j} $$

Now, for $i+j=n$, we get that the coefficient of $x^n$ is:  $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {r\choose i}{n-i+r-1\choose r-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{r} {r\choose i}{n-i+r-1\choose r-1} $$ Something that I am not able to simplify, and I am afraid that my answer (if correct) does not meet the criteria posed in the question.

I have tried to mess around with the expression but couldn't really simplify it.

Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: What is $n$ in your $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty \cdots$?

Comment: My bad I mixed some things up. It is supposed to be fixed now.

Comment: So then the later binomial coefficient should be $\binom{n-i+r-1}{r-1}$?

Comment: Why do you dislike the function $\left(\frac {1+x}{1-x} \right )^r $?

Comment: I dislike it because it is impossible to tell what is the coefficient of $x^n$ by looking at it.

Comment: kccu, you are correct I made a mistake. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

The generating function which you have found:
$$
\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^r
$$
completely satisfy the restriction:

> The function should be written explicitly (for example, not as a multiplication of two infinite series).

What concerns your main question I can suggest another representation of the sum:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^r\binom ri\binom{n-i+r-1}{r-1}=\sum_{i=1}^r\binom ri\binom{n-1}{i-1}2^i.
$$

I am not sure that this is a real simplification but it looks a little bit nicer.